# crm 2011 migrated to crm 2015 - http 401 for all webresources

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a problem after the migration CRM from 2011 to 2015. Both servers are in the same network but they are on different machines (crm 2011 is hosted on windows server 2008, crm 2015 -> windows server 2012, both on-premise) and use the same Active Directory. Even when I'm logged in as an administrator I can't reach any custom web resource. I can use CRM though. Everytime when js file or image is loaded user (including administrator) is getting credentials prompt. 
I tried different users but all had the same result. I tried to reach the file directly by typing URL into browser - the same... in the picture you can find some fiddler logs.

[image]

Comment: To upgrade from CRM 2011 to CRM 2015, you have to go through CRM 2013, and upgrade the CRM db. You will likely get odd behavior like this if you don't follow the proper upgrade process

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph stated, the move from 2011 directly to 2015 is unsupported. *However,* you may be able to fix this problem.

- Download XrmToolBox if you don't already have it.
- Connect to CRM 2011 organization.
- Run Web Resources Manager.
- Load web resources from CRM.
- Check all the web resources you wish to move.
- Select 'save checked web resources' (you can include the root if you wish).
- Disconnect and connect to CRM 2015.
- Run Web Resources Manager again.
- Load web resources from CRM.
- Delete the problematic web resources and add them in again.

I don't know for sure that this will solve your problem, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out - the problem wasn't related to CRM itself but the network infrastructure. I changed ASP.NET Authentication provider to NTLM (in IIS -> -> Authentication -> Windows Authentication (EnableD) -> Providers and moved NTLM to the top.

Then the 401 stopped appearing. It wasn't final solution because then I handover this issue to admins - but if you have simmilar problem it's worth to try this one.